# Named Pipes, Server question

Tags: c++, windows

I'm hanging on the WaitNamedPipe function even though I called CreateNamedPipe right before.  Since waitnamedpipe function just waits for the initiation of the pipe, why?  code is below.  thanks

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION po;
STARTUPINFO
s;

GetStartupInfo (&s);

if(CreateProcess ("c:\s2.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL,
                  NULL, &s, &po) == FALSE)
{
    printf("Error %d starting CC\n",
           GetLastError());
    exit(-1);

}

HANDLE pipe=CreateNamedPipe (pipe_name, 0x00000003,
                             FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
                             PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,128, 128, 0,
                             NULL);

while(WaitNamedPipe(pipe_name, INFINITE)==FALSE) Sleep(300);

HANDLE CC = CreateFile (pipe_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
                        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                        NULL);

bool fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, NULL) ? TRUE :
                  (GetLastError() ==
                   ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

if(fConnected) printf("true");
else printf("false");
```

Comment: Is there an actual question here?  I sure don't see one.

Answer (score 1):

`"C:\s2.exe"` is not `"C:\\s2.exe"`